# Codecademy code connect to Youtube API on their website but won't run locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a complete newbie, but I was doing the tutorial for connecting to the YouTube API and executing a search, which consists of making a search.js file and a search.html file.  The html then calls the search.js file which has the functions. Everything works fine in Codecademy and I can see the normal results for my youtube query. But I wanted to play around more, so I cut and pasted both files into .js and .html files put them into the same directory and tried to run it locally, but then I just get a blank html page.

The code is:

Search.js

```
function showResponse(response) {
    var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += responseString;
}

function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCR5In4DZaTP6IEZQ0r1JceuvluJRzQNLE');

    search();
}

function search() {
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: 'Ben Woods',
    });

    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}
```

Search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre id="response"></pre>
    </body>
 </html>
```

When I open the html doc I just get a blank page, and if I Alt+Command+J, I see the following errors:
 Denying load of chrome-extension://gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio/js/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
core:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2:838 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
cb=gapi.loaded_0:47 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

Comment: Try serving the page over a local server, eg via AMPPS or M/W/LAMP. You're requesting access to the API via a local file path with the `file://` protocol instead of the expected `http(s)://`.

Answer (score 4):

**IF** you have [Hola Better Internet](http://hola.org/), that's probably your problem.
I had the same problem for a while, I deleted everything even slightly related to `jquery/javascript` from my site but it didn't fix the problem. I deleted Hola from my Chrome and it solved the problem.

Comment: Not sure why you were being down-voted. Hola was also the culprit for me. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are running the files locally (via file://) but the API expects you to be calling it over http:// or https://. Instead of working locally, try using an online js playground like http://jsfiddle.net/